# Batch: Copy, then delete, files from list; need error handling

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've looked through the many batch-from-a-list topics on here, but haven't found anything on point. I have a text file with a list of files, including paths. I need to first copy these files out to an external drive, then delete the original files from the system drive. The batch file below works, with one glitch: I need to recreate the folder structure when the files are copied to the external drive. For example, if the file of interest is C:\foo\foo.txt, I need it to copy to a \foo directory on the external drive. I thought I had the xcopy parameters set to do that, but it's simply copying everything into one folder.

Next, I'd like to have some error handling in the batch file, in case some files aren't present.

Thanks a million for any help! Here's what I have so far...

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "D:\files.txt"') do xcopy  /shrkvy "%%a" "D:\Reclamation"
echo All files copied to reclamation folder.
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "D:\files.txt"') do del "%%a"
echo All files deleted from device.
pause
```

Comment: *"I need to recreate the folder structure when the files are copied to the external drive."* -- Overall, this sounds more like a job for [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) (which is also typically available at the command line) rather than a homebrew batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this. If a file fails to be copied it  is written to errors.txt and not deleted from the source. Successful copied filles are deleted from the source.

```
@echo off

set Source=D:\files.txt
set Destination=D:\Reclamation

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "%Source%"') do (
                                                         IF not exist "%Destination%%%~pa" md "%Destination%%%~pa"
                                                         xcopy /shrkvy "%%a" "%Destination%%%~pa"
                                                         IF NOT !ErrorLevel! EQU 0 (echo "%%a">>"Errors.txt") else (del /q "%%a")
                                                        )
```

Comment: Huge thanks, Ricardo. Works perfectly. One more question for you, if you have time. I decided it would be best to securely delete the files, and in place of **'del /q'** I inserted **'sdelete64 -q -z'**

That returns the error shown. Any ideas?

_C:\Test Files\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask
1 File(s) copied

SDelete v2.04 - Secure file delete
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Invalid option: C:\Test Files\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask
Target must be formatted as 'driveletter:' (e.g. 'd:') or disk number (e.g. '0')._

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the command sdelete64 I recommend you check its help sdelete64 /? or sdelete64 --help

Comment: It acts like the path and file to be deleted are not enclosed in quotes, but they are. Here's the sdelete command:  
**(sdelete64 -q -z "%%a")**